# how can i download data into s3 using a torrent file

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bittorrent, torrent

is it possible that i upload a torrent file in some web-app(may be angular) and then i link it to my aws s3 bucket.
after getting the torrent file, all the data inside that torrent is uploaded to my s3 bucket.

example: suppose i want to upload a movie "abc" in my s3 bucket..now instead of uploading the whole movie i only upload the torrent file and then aws(or maybe some other service) download data to my s3 bucket.

i found a method to distribute my content stored in aws s3 bucket in form of torrents but i want to do the reverse process.

the data should be transferred from cloud to cloud.

please suggest me a way to implement this idea

Comment: No, its not possible. You have to download it yourself, and then upload to s3.

Comment: @Marcin  can you please eloborate the answer that why its not possible?

Comment: How did it go? Have you checked s3fs?

Comment: @Marcin I gave it a look..but Actually there is a lot going on..hey can we get in touch ? to execute the idea

Comment: @Marcin no issues..i will surely do it

Comment: For what it's worth, s3fs won't work.  Or rather, it will, but it will cache the file locally while it's open, then upload it to S3 when it's done.  So, you can either download to an EC2 instance, then upload the file, or do the exact same thing with S3FS.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is [object storage system](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is-cloud-object-storage/), it is not a regular file system, and it can't be used in the same way as you are using your file system. AWS has dedicated service which you can use as file system, namely [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/). With EFS you can do what you wish, but not with S3.

However, there is an open-source, popular project called [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) which tries to mimic the use of S3 as a file system. Thus, you could have a look at it. Maybe it will suit your need.